# How to implement the RSMC part of Lightning network?

Tags: implementation, bitcoin, lightning-network

The Lightning Network consists of two contracts, RSMC(revocable sequence maturity contract) and HTLC. Now I  need to implement the RSMC part.

I understand the specific steps in the theory of the RSMC contract, but the implementation process encountered many difficulties.  Is there a step-by-step tutorial using existing libraries to implement the Lightning Network (mainly RSMC part)?

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer to your question is no. However there might be some steps that you could follow:

You can look at [BOLT3 which defines the RSMC](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/03-transactions.md#commitment-transaction#to_local-output) and the [Appendix of BOLT 5 might also be of use](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/05-onchain.md#expected-weight-of-the-to-local-penalty-transaction-witness). last but not least there are at least 5 implementations of the lightning network protocol out (c-lightning, lnd (go), eclair (scala), rust-lightning, and electrum (python)) you could look at the source code of any of those but I get the point that this might be quite a step and not exactly the step by step tutorial of making it yourself.